# The session.on("StreamCreated",functon()) not triggred when subscriber join the chat in Opentok.js

Tags: javascript, php, opentok

I'm using the Opentok.js library from video conferencing below is Js code.
but the Session.on("streamCreated",function(event){}); is not triggred when the subscriber joins the Room .

I'm using relayed base chat .

Any kind of help is appreciated . Thanks in advance .

```
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
var ping=function(pid){$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'https://hlg.tokbox.com/prod/logging/ClientEvent',
data:JSON.stringify({action:'sk_init',partner_id: pid,payload:{id:'link',l:'php',v:'1.0.0'}}),
processData:false, contentType: 'application/json'});};
</script>
<script>

var apiKey = "<?php echo $data['apiKey']?>",
session_id = "<?php echo $data['sessionId']?>",
token = "<?php echo $data['token'] ?>",
property = { insertMode: "append" },
publisher = OT.initPublisher("myPublisher", property),
session = OT.initSession(apiKey, session_id);

session.connect( token, function(err) {
  if(!err) { session.publish(publisher); }
  //userType = session.connection.data;

});

console.log("before stream created for subscriber",session.on());

session.on("streamCreated", function(event) {
  alert("stream" + event.stream);
  session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber',  property);
});

console.log("after stream created for subscriber");

session.connect(token, function(err) {
  if(!err){ session.publish(publisher); }
});

ping(apiKey);
```

And Php server side

```
$opentok = new OpenTok('45433942', 'f4c2aa60dc4febfb78fc5eead865adb46c613035');
    $session = $opentok->createSession();
    $sessionId = $session->getSessionId();
    $token = $opentok->generateToken($sessionId);

    $data = array(
            'apiKey'=>'45433942',
            'token'=>$token,
            'sessionId'=>$sessionId
        );
    return View::make('opentok/index')->with('data',$data);
```

Comment: Do you use same session for a room or generate every time? You must use one common session for a room. And one more thing, publisher can not listen his own stream created event in Opentok.

Comment: yeah , I'm generating the session for php-sdk  server code and maintain that session id for each and every users that joins the chat

Comment: Write your publishing code in one file and listening 'Stream Created' event in another. Make sure there must be only one session used for publishing and listening. Publisher can't listen his own stream as he can view it!

Comment: Thanks you answer BCoder , I done this functionality with another way 
Thanks